# Replacing Fragment with fragment in activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an `Activity` that has a `Fragment` (Frag A) added to it in its `onCreate` method. This `Fragment` contains the UI elements i would like the activity to display on default. On button click in frag A, i would like to replace Frag A with another fragment(Frag B) that shows a progress bar. If there is a configuration while Frag B is showing, Frag(A) should not be added when the activity's onCreate method is called.

How can i achieve this?

Just like its done in this facebook app:

[image: First Screen showing UI]
[image: Second sreeen showing progress bar after button click in]

I've tried a lot of methods:

1. First i added the UI elements directly in the activity's layout along with an empty framelayout, so on button click i hide the UI elements and do a `Fragment` transaction to put my fragment containing my progress bar in the framelayout, this works fine but if there is configuration change the activity is recreated and i am back to square one.

This is what i have now.

**MainActivity**

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  {
Button button;
private ProgressDialog mpDialog;
boolean running;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.wrapper, fragment).commit();

}



public void Click() {
    TaskFragment taskFragment = new TaskFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.wrapper, taskFragment).commit();

}


 }
```

**MainFragment(Holding UI elements)**

```
    public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

View fView;
ProgressBar bar;
TextView textView;
Button button;
MainActivity activity = new MainActivity();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    fView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mainfragment, container, false);
    textView = (TextView) fView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
    button = (Button) fView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    clicked();
    return fView;
}


private void clicked() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            activity.Click();
        }
    });

}

   }
```

**TaskFragment(Showing progress bar)**

```
   public class TaskFragment extends Fragment{

View fview;
ProgressBar bar;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    fview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.progressfragment, container, false);
    bar = (ProgressBar) fview.findViewById(R.id.sendingSmsProgress);
    return fview;
}

 }
```

**The Error i get when i try to switch fragments**

```
  03-14 05:41:44.457: E/AndroidRuntime(11049): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  03-14 05:41:44.457: E/AndroidRuntime(11049): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
  03-14 05:41:44.457: E/AndroidRuntime(11049):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1365)
  03-14 05:41:44.457: E/AndroidRuntime(11049):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
  03-14 05:41:44.457: E/AndroidRuntime(11049):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
  03-14 05:41:44.457: E/AndroidRuntime(11049):  at com.example.test.MainActivity.Click(MainActivity.java:41)
  03-14 05:41:44.457: E/AndroidRuntime(11049):  at com.example.test.MainFragment$1.onClick(MainFragment.java:47)
  03-14 05:41:44.457: E/AndroidRuntime(11049):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4102)
  03-14 05:41:44.457: E/AndroidRuntime(11049):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17085)
  03-14 05:41:44.457: E/AndroidRuntime(11049):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
  03-14 05:41:44.457: E/AndroidRuntime(11049):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  03-14 05:41:44.457: E/AndroidRuntime(11049):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
  03-14 05:41:44.457: E/AndroidRuntime(11049):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5454)
  03-14 05:41:44.457: E/AndroidRuntime(11049):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  03-14 05:41:44.457: E/AndroidRuntime(11049):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  03-14 05:41:44.457: E/AndroidRuntime(11049):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
  03-14 05:41:44.457: E/AndroidRuntime(11049):  at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
  03-14 05:41:44.457: E/AndroidRuntime(11049):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the fragment from the fragment use like this

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame, new DialogFragment()).commit();
```

Comment: Yeah I've done that. And the fragment gets replaced,. But when I recreate my activity while the dialogframent is showing, the initial fragment is reloaded. I don't want the initial fragment to show if a configuration change occurs while dialog fragment is showing

Comment: override configuration changes in fragment and mention in manifast. if not works commitAllowingStateLoss() use instead of commit. if there exists any async task in that fragment it will execute by default you can set any condition there to prevent it from recreating.